# Was Sallah the husband of Adrian Eldrich before?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e, romance

From *[NetherWar #2: The Pentagram Peril](https://greenroninstore.com/products/astonishing-adventures-netherwar-2-pentagram-peril-pdf?_pos=1&_sid=b36598aed&_ss=r)*

> The event’s guest of honor is Sallah, Adrian Eldrich’s surviving partner.
> A handsome older Egyptian man, he retains legal control of his departed husband’s legacy and has worked closely with the museum to make
> sure the artifacts and documents on loan are treated with respect and
> caution. The heroes briefly encountered an unconscious Sallah if they
> played through Assault on the Nerian Nexus, and if so, he takes the opportunity to thank them again for their aid that night. If this is their first
> meeting, Sallah is polite enough, and curious about any magical powers
> among their number. The old man is fastidious and soft-spoken, with
> keen observation skills and a dry wit. His favorite topic of conversation
> is Adrian and their unusual adventures, and he’s happy to talk about the
> former Master Mage to anyone who will listen, peppering the mythology and adventures stories with occasional romantic insights. While he
> has mostly come to terms with his partner’s passing, he still sighs and
> wipes away the occasional tear as he speaks

Poking through the previous editions of *Freedom City* (I have copies of all three), *Book of Magic*, and the other *NetherWar* adventures, this is the first I've seen mention of Sallah and Adrian being romantically entangled, all of the prior descriptions having him be the archetypical "faithful manservant". Recognizing, of course, that Freedom City has long been a bit more inclusive of different sexual orientations, reflective of author Steve Kenson, it feels odd that this should show up a few decades after the character was introduced. Were there earlier mentions of their relationship being romantic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still don't have this is an easily citeable form, but during the [August 24, 2020 M&M Monday Facebook livecast](https://www.facebook.com/GreenRonin/videos/246578143113811?notif_id=1598303221129401&notif_t=live_video_explicit&ref=notif) at about 10:24, I was able to ask the question as to whether this information had appeared before and Steve Kenson responded.

> No, it hasn't. You are privileged to see a first reveal about their relationship.